# TLS handshake in HTTP connection confusion

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, https, hsts

**Hi Everyone, my apologies. We are now 1.5 years later and I was looking over this article again and I realize that the question I had was very poorly contructed. I will try to reformulate it properly.**

I've read about HTTPS redirections, HSTS, SSL renegotiation and so on.

When I read about HSTS redirections, the article mentions that HSTS redirects will be encrypted. Following common sense this means that the HTTP to HTTPS redirects using HSTS are performed **after** a SSL/TLS handshake.

But obviously, HTTP Client-Server communication is done in plain text. How can this be the case if at the same time the TLS handshake (deciding on security parameters) is done **before** the HTTP request is sent (read article below)? I always assumed there was **no** TLS handshake and definitely **no** SSL/TLS encryption before and during a plain text HTTP conversation (including the original request and reply).

So simply put:
How can the server redirect the client in an encryted way without having negotiated any specifics on the ecryption beforehand?

Or, if a TLS handshake is always performed as a first step in any web request (HTTP or HTTPS), how is it possible that HTTP communication ends up being plain text?

Or is the article below mentioning this incorrectly?

Thanks in advance for going through the effort! I really appreciate it!

.

Article:

https://blog.dnsimple.com/2016/08/https-redirects/

Comment: HTTPS is HTTP over TLS, that should explain most of it. TLS is a transport protocol, agnostic to what it transports; HTTP is the application protocol that exchange specific messages formatted in specific ways.

Comment: Your question is confusing and I don't really understand what your problem is.  The question is probably more on-topic on security.stackexchange.com anyway. But note that there are several questions already which ask about sslstrip so I recommend to have a look first if your question is already answered.

Comment: If you connect to bbc.com with http that is an unsecured connection, no SSL at all. An HTTP redirect to HTTPS happens **in the clear, and is thus vulnerable**. That's why HSTS is good, because that tells the browser to *only connect over SSL*.

Comment: @JamesKPolk That's not what the websites are saying. they state that the redirects happen after the TLS handshake and thus encrypted. As for Patrick Mevzek and Steffen Ullrich, I don't understand how the http to https redirect can happen after the TLS handshake and encrypted, in my head that means we don't need HTTPS to exchange encrypted web traffic.

Comment: The first link says that **https** redirects happen under tls, which is correct. It mentions in one spot an HTTP redirect but doesn't really say what happens there. The second link never says that either. You can verify all this yourself with wireshark.

Comment: Hey @JamesKPolk, sorry for coming back to this after such a long time. Does this mean that I have to assume when they list: "In the second step, the client prepares the HTTP request, encrypts it, and sends it to the server for processing. The server receives the encrypted HTTP request, decrypts it, processes the HTTP request, and produces an HTTP response." in the article, they actually mean an HTTPS request where they talk about encrypted HTTP request? :)